# az graph query and tsv

Tags: azure, csv, graph

I have problems to understand what i´m missing. I want the result in a table that I could use in MS Excel. It will be used get the count of cores used in a subscription.

What are missing?

If I run following:

```
az graph query -q "Resources | where type =~ 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines' | project name, size = properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize, properties.licenseType, resourceGroup, subscriptionId, type, properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType"
```

It returns what I expected.

When I try to add `-o tsv` at the end:

```
az graph query -q "Resources | where type =~ 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines' | project name, size = properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize, properties.licenseType, resourceGroup, subscriptionId, type, properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType" -o tsv
```

It returns: the count of virtual machines in my subscription (8 8 none 8).

If I run following:

```
az graph query --first 1000 -o tsv -q "project name, size = properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize, properties.licenseType, resourceGroup, subscriptionId, type, properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType  | where type =~ 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'"
```

Is the result the same 8  8  none 8.

What I want is that output should be in a table.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried running the above shared sample query from cloud shell in my subscription and the cmdlet`az graph query` is generating the below output

```
"count" :"",
"data":[] , <All project parameters are getting logged in data[] array>,
"skip_token": null
"Total_records": ""
```

Since you are trying to project the output of project columns in tsv or in table format you need to make the below change to above cmdlet.

```
az graph query -q "Resources | where type =~ 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines' | project name, size = properties.hardwareProfile.vmSize, properties.licenseType, resourceGroup, subscriptionId, type, properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType" --query data --output table
```

[image]